# install CGAL (3.3), QT not find, no target to build

Tags: qt, cgal

I'm trying to install a previous version of CGAL (version 3.3) that I have downloaded on Ubuntu. When I run as said in the readMe:

```
 ./install_cgal -i
```

and press 'B' for building, I get the following error:

```
OS:             x86-64_Linux-3.16
COMPILER:           GNU 4.8.4
BOOST:  supported (1.54.0)
BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS:  supported (1.54.0)
BOOST_BIMAP:    not supported
X11:    supported (11.0)
GMP:    supported (5.1.3)
GMPXX:  supported (5.1.3)
MPFR:   supported (3.1.2)
ZLIB:   supported (1.2.8)
BLAS:   not supported
LAPACK: not supported
ATLAS:  not supported
LIDIA:  not supported
LEDA:   not supported
LEDAWIN:    not supported
OPENGL: supported (2.1)
QT: not supported  ----> even if QT4 and QT5 are installed
TAUCS:  not supported

Generating Makefiles ... done.
Building libCGAL static ...
Compilation of libCGAL static failed.

make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « assertions.o »,     
nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « 
Bbox_2_intersections.o », nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « 
 Bbox_3_intersections.o », nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « cgal_logo.o », 
nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « Color.o », 
nécessaire 
pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « 
File_header_extended_OFF.o », nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « File_header_OFF.o », 
nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « File_scanner_OFF.o», 
nécessaire pour « libCGAL.a ».
make: La cible « static_lib » n'a pas pu être refabriquée à cause 
d'erreurs.
```

I tried to specify the paths for QT. For this, I return to menu and type 'S' for support menu, and then select QT:

```
Set QT_INCL_DIR                                     
  /usr/include/qt4/                                 
Set QT_LIB_DIR                                      
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

This doesn't allow to detect QT4. Any ideas please ?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use such an old version?

Comment: As you are new to CGAL you better use the latest version.

Comment: I'm using a source code of surface descriptors that uses CGAL 3.3. I've installed the latest version of CGAL, however the source code associated to the descriptor didn't worked because of  some includes of CGAL. This is why I want to install the 3.3 version